# Get Work Items by WorkItemType in TFS REST API

Tags: c#, tfs

I am new to using TFS REST API. I need to query work items by work item type.
The following link only shows to query work items by ids:

[Work Items TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#get-a-list-of-work-items)

Has anyone figured out how to query work items by WorkItemType ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. We need to include a WIQL query in a POST call.

More details can be found here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql